# Get feature at specific coordinate with PyQgis

Tags: pyqgis, pyqgis-3

I am using QGIS 3.2 and I am trying to get the features at a specific coordinate for a specific layer. when I use mouse position event the following code works fine but when I calculate the coordinate and use Identify tool. It doesn't work. 
I do some calculation in my program to get the coordinates, then that coordinate goes to following code to get the features but the following codes returns empty.

```
for lyr in [layer for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()]:
        if lyr.name() == 'equipment':
            LayerID = lyr
            print(lyr)
canvas=iface.mapCanvas()
f=QgsMapToolIdentify(canvas).identify(151.111650,-33.793260,[LayerID],QgsMapToolIdentify.TopDownAll)
print(f)
```

The following picture shows the coordinate of the the equipment but this code returns empty list

[image]

I have tried the following:

- Increasing the search Radius in QGIS option (even 50.0mm returns empty)
- give the input as QgsPoint

To make it clear I should explain that the coordinate not necessarily intersect with the feature coordinate(in most cases it Does). 
I managed to get around the issue by writing the following code. It does what I need but the issue is. It is too Slow with big data set. Does QGIS have a better way to handle this?

```
def tool_identifier(self,layer_name,point_x,point_y,buffer=3):
    """ The only reason I created this is because I couldnt do it with maptool Identifier
    this tool gets two coordinate x and y and checks a layer if there is a feature in the buffer it will be add to output list

    :param Layer_name: Qgis Layer name should be Already open.
    :type Layer_name: string

    :param point_x: x coordinate of the center of buffer.
    :type point_x: float (151.117596)

    :param point_x: x coordinate of the center of buffer.
    :type point_x: float (-33.794810)

    :param buffer: this is the buffer radious 
    :type buffer: it should be a number and default value is 3m

    """

    identified_feature_list=[]
    distance = QgsDistanceArea()
    for lyr in [layer for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()]:
        if lyr.name() == layer_name:layer_obj = lyr

    for f in layer_obj.getFeatures():
        distance = QgsDistanceArea()
        distance.setEllipsoid('WGS84')
        geom = f.geometry()
        current_point=geom.asPoint()
        m = distance.measureLine(QgsPointXY(current_point.x(),current_point.y()), QgsPointXY(point_x,point_y))
        if m<buffer:
            identified_feature_list.append(f)

    return identified_feature_list
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To apply a search distance around your coordinates, construct a `QgsGeometry` object from a `QgsPointXY` object created from your coordinates. Then you can use the `buffer()` method to create the search zone.

To do the actual geometric test, you can use a `QgsSpatialIndex` and `QgsGeometryEngine` which should be fast on your large data set.

```
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('equipment')[0]
pnt = QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(151.111650,-33.793260))
buffer_dist = 3# meters

index = QgsSpatialIndex(layer.getFeatures())

def transform_buffer_distance(dist):
    da = QgsDistanceArea()
    da.setEllipsoid('WGS84')
    dist = da.convertLengthMeasurement(dist, QgsUnitTypes.DistanceDegrees)
    return dist

search_radius = pnt.buffer(transform_buffer_distance(buffer_dist), 25)
engine = QgsGeometry.createGeometryEngine(search_radius.constGet())
engine.prepareGeometry()

matches = [f.id() for f in layer.getFeatures(index.intersects(search_radius.boundingBox())) if engine.contains(f.geometry().constGet())]
layer.selectByIds(matches)
print(matches)
```

Comment: Your answer works well when the calculated point intersects but the problem is the coordinate I calculate not necessarily intersect with the feature. then I need to search inside a Buffer. Does PyQGIS has such a function As I don't want to reinvent a weel.

Comment: @Ehsan Aliverdi, several years after originally answering this question, I have updated my answer, to show how to search within a buffer and also how to use a spatial index and geometry engine to speed up the analysis on large datasets.